# Tortoise ORM - InterfaceError in _acquire Pool is closing

Tags: python, celery, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I am using FastAPI with tortoise orm.
I am trying to handle around 4 to 5 data retrievals and updating the data.
Every time I update, I am locking the database row using `select_for_update` and update the data.
My whole process runs in the background with celery.
I get the below error.
Has anyone faced similar issue and found solution on this?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tortoise/queryset.py", line 1006, in _execute
  instance_list = await self._db.executor_class(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tortoise/backends/base/executor.py", line 130, in execute_select
  _, raw_results = await self.db.execute_query(query.get_sql())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tortoise/backends/base_postgres/client.py", line 24, in _translate_exceptions
  return await self._translate_exceptions(func, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tortoise/backends/asyncpg/client.py", line 79, in _translate_exceptions
  return await func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tortoise/backends/asyncpg/client.py", line 126, in execute_query
  async with self.acquire_connection() as connection:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tortoise/backends/base/client.py", line 328, in __aenter__
  self.connection = await self.pool.acquire()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 822, in _acquire
  raise exceptions.InterfaceError('pool is closing')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, it is like the connection for other pool is still open, you need to close all the connection when the process is done

https://github.com/tortoise/aerich/issues/212